# How to display image in html from function javascript? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

halo guys can you help me to display image. How to display image in html from function javascript? ASP.NET
this is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="DisplayImage" class="img-responsive thumbnail" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

javascript here =

```
var DisplayImage = function () {
    var file = $("#SelectImage").get(0).files;
    var data = new FormData;
    data.append("ImageFile", file[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Home/DisplayImage',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (imgID) {
            
            $("#DisplayImage").show();
            $("#img_cgv").attr("src", "/UploadImage/" + imgID);
            console.log(imgID);
        }
    })
}
```

my controller :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DisplayImage(int imgid)
        {
            Models.eCoalDataContext db = new eCoalDataContext();
            var img = db.TBL_M_IMAGEs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == imgid);
            /*return File("image/jpg");*/
            return File(img.IMAGE_TITLE, "image/jpg");
        }
```

Comment: What's your img's value ? Could you share the code of your TBL_M_IMAGEs?

Comment: public int ID { get; set; }
        public string IMAGE_TITLE { get; set; }
        public string IMAGE_PATH { get; set; }

Comment: Are you able to hot your controller DisplayImage(..) method?

Comment: Also make sure that your returning image path should look something like http:// instead of /Content/myfile.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code about your files, so in my demo I remove it. Below is a work demo  to display image in html from function javascript, you can refer to it, hope it can help you.

Besides, in I have e.PNG  in  UploadImage folder like:

[image]

In Controller:

```
public class DisplayController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
     
        public ActionResult DisplayImage(int imgid)
        {
            imgid = 1;         
            var Images = new List<Images>()
            { new Images(){ID=1,IMAGE_TITLE="e.PNG"},
            new Images(){ID=2,IMAGE_TITLE="flower.PNG"}
            };
            var img = Images.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == imgid);          
            return Json(img.IMAGE_TITLE);
           
        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
<input onclick="getA1Rates()" value="Click" type="button"/>

<div class="col-md-4">  
    <img id="img_cgv" class="img-responsive thumbnail" width="200" height="200" /> 
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getA1Rates() {      
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Display/DisplayImage',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (imgID) {            
                $("#img_cgv").attr("src", "/UploadImage/" + imgID);
                console.log(imgID);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Hanung Risqi , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.